# HTML5 editor / library to insert image into HTML automatically

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, editor

I want HTML editor or JavaScript library that when **dropping image in HTML** spot (`<div>, <section>` etc) does these:
1) put images in the same folder that this .html file
2) inserts HTML tag for image `<a href="/"><img src="image.png" alt="image"></a>`

Comment: Every HTML editor let you edit HTML tags, what about generating those tag when dropping image with mouse

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into something thats open source like [`eclipse`](https://www.eclipse.org/)

[image: eclipse html ide]
<sub>(source: [eclipse4you.com](http://www.eclipse4you.com/files/eclipse_plugins/richhtml4eclipse.png))</sub>

[`netbeans`](https://netbeans.apache.org/)

[image: netbeans ide]
<sub>(source: [netbeans.org](https://platform.netbeans.org/images/tutorials/htmleditor/73/pic10.png))</sub>

or even [`aptana`](http://www.aptana.com/) is great.

Comment: I have just checked Eclipse Juno. HTML Editor has no support for dropping images.

Comment: Look into [`Dreamweaver`](http://www.adobe.com/nz/products/dreamweaver.html), aptana's html ide is very similar to dreamweaver (you will need to install plugins for each of these to get them to work the way you want).